# pyautogui: LocateOnScreen possible with boolean true/false?

Tags: python, pyautogui

Edit: the problem seems to stem from these lines:

```
apply = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("apply.png")
if apply is not None:
    x, y = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('apply.png')
    pyautogui.click(x,y)
```

### is there anyway to make it so that you can run an if statement to check if the image is there?

Warning: very new with python

My objective it to automate job applying on indeed.ca using the latest version of firefox, fully maximized window. So far i'm just working on 1 page and the code is not perfect. It starts out, clicks on the first job position, locates the "apply now" orange button on the right, clicks it which opens a form, fills out the form, uploads resume, clicks continue, then clicks apply which submits the final form.

I'm having 2 problems:

1. i'm not sure how to tell the program: If this image does exist anywhere on page. instead I have `if apply is not None:` which i'm not sure if it is working or not. I only know that `if applynow == None:` is working.
2. I ran a test on one of the job positions, it was supposed to submit it but gave me an error message of "TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object" which means the image does not exist... That's great, but that part is in the else statement, not the initial if statement. The initial if statement was supposed to trigger first... so it was supposed to just click on apply instead of going through the else statement, so either the image of "apply" is not being detected or python needs to run through the else statement before executing which messes up the execution if that makes any sense. I'm not sure which problem i'm facing, so any help is appreciated.

error:

```
    x, y = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('continue2.png')
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
```

link: https://www.indeed.ca/jobs?q=engineer&l=Vancouver%2C%20BC&start=40&vjk=64c9d891c652bd2b

```
import pyautogui, time

pyautogui.PAUSE = 1
pyautogui.FAILSAFE = True
time.sleep(5)
pyautogui.click(863,330)

applynow = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("applynow.png")
confirmyourapplication = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("confirmyourapplication.png")
confirmonnextpage = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("confirmonnextpage.png")
howmanyyears = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("howmanyyears.png")
apply = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("apply.png")

for i in range (0, 9):
    if applynow == None:
        pyautogui.scroll(-425)
        x, y = pyautogui.position()
        pyautogui.click(x,y)
    else:
        x, y = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('applynow.png')
        pyautogui.click(x,y)
        pyautogui.press('tab')
        pyautogui.press('tab')
        pyautogui.typewrite('Jake Williams', 0.25)
        pyautogui.press('tab')
        pyautogui.typewrite('jwilliam02@hotmail.com', 0.25)
        pyautogui.press('tab')
        pyautogui.typewrite('719-985-3546', 0.25)
        x, y = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('browse.png')
        pyautogui.click(x,y)
        pyautogui.typewrite('resume', 0.25)
        pyautogui.press('enter')
        x, y = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('continue.png')
        pyautogui.click(x,y)
        time.sleep(2)
        ## insert function here
        if apply is not None:
            x, y = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('apply.png')
            pyautogui.click(x,y)
            x, y = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('close.png')
            pyautogui.click(x,y)
        else:
            for j in range (0, 3):
                if howmanyyears is not None:
                    x, y = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('howmanyyears.png')
                    pyautogui.click(x,y)
                    pyautogui.typewrite('3', 0.25)
            x, y = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('continue2.png')
            pyautogui.click(x,y)
            time.sleep(2)
            x, y = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('apply.png')
            pyautogui.click(x,y)
            x, y = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('close.png')
            pyautogui.click(x,y)
```

Comment: Why aren't u using some browser automation tool instead of pyautogui?

Comment: selenium triggers captcha even if you only open the browser with it.

Answer (score 0):

try using this code:

```
#code before if statement here  
#the code below is an if statement replacement  
#tab button on my keyboard doesn't work, replacing it with spaces  
try:  
    x, y = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('continue2.png')  
except TypeError:  
    #insert code to run if the image isn't located  
else:  
    #insert code to run if the image is located  
finally:  
    #insert rest of program here
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually get this error when I didn't find the image.

```
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
```

Try to make sure the image is on the screen without obstructuions.